# Too many GET /info requests for SockJS on spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/java/stomp-spring-boot-websocket) to setup WebSockets using SockJS between an Angular application and Spring Boot. All was working fine up until sometime ago a lot of `GET /info` requests flood the server whenever I enable `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` as a result of which the opened file count on the server goes to the roof shutting down the server. The opened files count on server goes to 2000+ because of this.

Any idea what can be the reason for such large requests coming in because in reality there are very few active connected clients. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just an updated: we followed https://dzone.com/articles/full-duplex-scalable-client-server-communication-2 and also on the client side application we added updated the logic of automatically reconnecting websockets incase of disconnect, and were able to solve the issue for now. For now we are not getting flooded with GET /info requests anymore primarily I think it was related to the reconnect logic on the client due to which it was constantly firing incase it didnt get a valid response from server